# Do I need a map using @POST with jersey in tomcat

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to create a rest API with Jersey in a tomcat server, my application collects input from other services (no database).
I have created the following pojos:

```
//this a pojo for parameters the application takes in the @POST request, a location lat/long

@XmlRootElement
public class DestLatLong {
    private String lat;
    private String lng;

    public DestLatLong(){}

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

}
```

These are the values that will be included in the response, ticket price to get to the given location:

```
public class DestPriceResponse {

    public DestPriceResponse() {
    }
    public String airport;
    public String currency;
    public String price;
    public String getAirport() {
        return airport;
    }
    public void setAirport(String airport) {
        this.airport = airport;
    }
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Do I need to use a map here instead for the pojo to map correctly into JSON? or is this object enough?

Below is the class that should be handling the requests and return the responses:

```
public class DestinationResource {


// Will map the resource to the URL todos
@Path("/api")
public class TodosResource {

    // Allows to insert contextual objects into the class,
    // e.g. ServletContext, Request, Response, UriInfo
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public DestPriceResponse getDestPrice(String lat, String lng) {
        DestPriceResponse priceResponse = new DestPriceResponse();

        NearestAirports nearest = new NearestAirports();
        nearest.parseNearestAirports(lat, lng);
        return priceResponse;
    }
```

The POST request I'm using is :

`http://localhost:8080/webapi/rest/api?lat=60&lng=0`

and the header has:

`Content-Type = application/json`

but I keep getting:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message Not Found
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

My settings include:

`rootProject.name = 'webapi'`

and webxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>webapi</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>webapi</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What is wrong, how can I best debug this?

Answer (score 2):

This call `http://localhost:8080/webapi/rest/api?lat=60&lng=0` assumes you are exposing HTTP `GET` method that uses `@QueryParam()` annotation on `getDestPrice()` method arguments (lat and lng) as follow:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public DestPriceResponse getDestPrice(@QueryParam("lat") String lat, @QueryParam("lng") String lng) {
```

If you want to use `POST` method that accepts a data object, you should change your method signature to the following:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public DestPriceResponse getDestPrice(DestLatLong longLat) {
```

- Change your HTTP call and use any HttpClient ([Advanced Rest
     Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) chrome extension for example)
- add header of `Content-Type: application/json` and pass the json
  describing `DestLatLong` object
- `Jersey` will create this object for you on runtime when calling the api.

You're getting error 404 because you don't have a HTTP GET endpoint on `/` (you defined POST instead)

Comment: thanks @Gal for the answer. I found that the GET would be an easier approach, so I've followed the example above. Yet when I make a GET request to the endpoint with my httpClient I still get a not found. Could it be a routing problem, any easy way of debugging that and getting to the root cause?